# Debain Package rebuild

Tags: linux, deb

I've downloaded .deb package
[image: tcpdump tool debian package]

Then I've extracted all the data from the current .deb file and add a new file with arbitrary content.
[image]

My question: how can I create a new .deb package from this modified directory */tmp/tcpdump*?

Answer (score 0):

Create a necessity directory structure, then:

```
dpkg-deb --build package_name
```

Found answer here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=910717